# How to align text below an image in CSS?

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
  <div class="image1">
      <img src="images/img1.png" width="250" height="444" alt="Screen 1"/>
      <img src="images/img2.png" width="250" height="444" alt="Screen 2"/>
      <img src="../images/img3.png" width="250" height="444" alt="Screen 3"/>
  </div>
```

If I add a paragraph text between img1 and img2 they get separated (img2 goes to a newline)

What I'm attempting to do is this (with some space between the images):

```
[image1] [image2] [image3]
 [text]   [text]   [text]
```

I haven't given the images their own individual class names because the images don't align horizontally to one another.

Comment: Create a JSFiddle, please, to help understanding the scenario correctly.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Add a container div for the image and the caption:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
</div>
```

Then, with a bit of CSS, you can make an automatically wrapping image gallery:

```
div.item {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
}
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.caption {
    display: block;
}
```

```css
div.item {
    /* To correctly align image, regardless of content height: */
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    /* To horizontally center images and caption */
    text-align: center;
    /* The width of the container also implies margin around the images. */
    width: 120px;
}
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.caption {
    /* Make the caption a block so it occupies its own line. */
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <span class="caption">An even longer text below the image which should take up multiple lines.</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <span class="caption">An even longer text below the image which should take up multiple lines.</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZhLk4/1/

**Updated answer**

Instead of using 'anonymous' div and spans, you can also use the HTML5 `figure` and `figcaption` elements. The advantage is that these tags add to the semantic structure of the document. Visually there is no difference, but it may (positively) affect the usability and indexability of your pages.

The tags are different, but the structure of the code is exactly the same, as you can see in this updated snippet and fiddle:

```html
<figure class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <figcaption class="caption">Text below the image</figcaption>
</figure>
```

```css
figure.item {
    /* To correctly align image, regardless of content height: */
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    /* To horizontally center images and caption */
    text-align: center;
    /* The width of the container also implies margin around the images. */
    width: 120px;
}
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.caption {
    /* Make the caption a block so it occupies its own line. */
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<figure class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <figcaption class="caption">Text below the image</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <figcaption class="caption">Text below the image</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <figcaption class="caption">An even longer text below the image which should take up multiple lines.</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <figcaption class="caption">Text below the image</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <figcaption class="caption">Text below the image</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <figcaption class="caption">An even longer text below the image which should take up multiple lines.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZhLk4/379/

Comment: is it necessary to make div element to "inline-block"? If I make div element to inline-block then it doesnt let any other div to be placed in the same row

Comment: @Teddu It's necessary to make in `inline-block` mainly because other divs can be next to it then. The alternative would be to use float, but I'm usually not so happy with it. Did you give the div a width? Without a (small) width, the div may occupy a too large space, and because of that push the other divs to the next line.

Answer (score 4):

Best way is to wrap the Image and Paragraph text with a DIV and assign a class.

### Example:

```
<div class="image1">
    <div class="imgWrapper">
        <img src="images/img1.png" width="250" height="444" alt="Screen 1"/>
        <p>It's my first Image</p>
    </div>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: dont forget to set text-align:center to the wrapper

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way excpecially if you don't know images widths is to put the caption in it's own div element an define it to be cleared:both !

...

```
<div class="pics">  
    <img class="marq" src="pic_1.jpg" />
    <div class="caption">My image 1</div>
</div>  
<div class="pics">  
    <img class="marq" src="pic_2.jpg" />
    <div class="caption">My image 2</div>
</div>
```

...

and in style-block define

```
div.caption: {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the default for block elements is to order one on top of the other you should also be able to do this:

```
<div>
    <img src="path/to/img">
    <div>Text Under Image</div>
</div

img {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a jsfiddle for you here: [JSFiddle HTML & CSS Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8z46G/)

**CSS**

```
div.raspberry {
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
}

div p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML** (apply CSS above to get what you need)

```
<div>
    <div class = "raspberry">
        <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lwlpl7ZE4z1r8f9ino1_500.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Screen 2"/>
        <p>Raspberry <br> For You!</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "raspberry">
        <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lwlpl7ZE4z1r8f9ino1_500.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Screen 3"/>
        <p>Raspberry <br> For You!</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "raspberry">
        <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lwlpl7ZE4z1r8f9ino1_500.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Screen 3"/>
        <p>Raspberry <br> For You!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML5 Caption feature.

Comment: @desingerNProgrammer that's the perfect answer.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of images i choose background option:

HTML:

```
  <div class="class1">
   <p>Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, 
   </p>
  </div>    
  <div class="class2">
   <p>Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, 
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="class3">
   <p>Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, Some paragraph, 
   </p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .class1 {

    background: url("Some.png") no-repeat top center;
    text-align: center;

   }

  .class2 {

    background: url("Some2.png") no-repeat top center;
    text-align: center;

   }

  .class3 {

    background: url("Some3.png") no-repeat top center;
    text-align: center;

   }
```