# Center text under image in flex container

Tags: html, css

I'm aware of [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592064/how-to-align-text-below-an-image-in-css) and many others like it. I have reviewed several edge cases similar to mine, and none of the fixes I've tried have worked.

I have an image and text. I want the text centered below the image. What I'm getting is the paragraph always aligned to the left edge of the image and growing to the right, rather than being centered on the image such as the image below. The image itself has even-width transparent borders on each edge, the size of which you can determine by knowing the left edge of the paragraph is aligned with the left edge of the image (it's very small).

[image: text aligned to left of image]

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

#myLinks {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
  background: black;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.menu-card {
  height: 15vh;
  width: 5vw;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 16%;
  border-radius: 45px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-icon-container {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-icon {
  max-height: 10vh;
  max-width: 5vw;
}

.card-text {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 45px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="myLinks">
  <div class="menu-card">
    <div class="menu-icon-container">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="menu-icon" src="http://placehold.it/100x300" id="portfolio-icon">
        <p class="card-text">Portfolio</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TheVigilant for putting me on the right path:

```
.menu-icon-container a {
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content : center;
}

.menu-icon-container > img, p {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **margin:auto** to get this fixed. 
Add a class **.center-items** to the parent **a** tag of the image with the following properties :

```
.center-items > img,p {
  display : block;
  margin : auto ;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

#myLinks {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
  background: black;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.menu-card {
  height: 15vh;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 16%;
  border-radius: 45px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-icon-container {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-icon {
  max-height: 10vh;
  max-width: 5vw;
}

.card-text {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 45px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
.center-items > img,p {
display : block;
  margin : auto ;
}
```

```html
<div id="myLinks">
  <div class="menu-card">
    <div class="menu-icon-container">
      <a href="#" class="center-items">
        <img class="menu-icon" src="http://placehold.it/100x300" id="portfolio-icon">
        <p class="card-text">Portfolio</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the top parent is a flex container, and justify-content has no effect

Comment: @froggomad you can define that **a** tag as flex item as well, though and it will work

Comment: I changed `.menu-icon-container` to match your specs and there was no change

Comment: I missed that you suggested it on the `a` tag as that's the direct parent, but I did that as well just now and its the same

Comment: @froggomad I am proposing to add  the class to the  **a** tag which is containing that image and the paragraph

Comment: @froggomad Its working in the snippet I have added to my answer

Comment: If you notice, the image in your snippet is matching the paragraph size. If I change the max width of the image to a small size, say 50px - the problem persists.

Comment: Can you check it now ? @froggomad I have added another fix

Answer (score 0):

it may work.. plz modify the css code..

**css**

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* Removes padding behaviour on widths */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu-card {
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no change.

Comment: No.. The image is centered.. U can upload large size image and then check.. and reply me.. no pbm

Comment: OP is asking about the text being centered not the image.

Comment: .card-text {text-align:center;} .menu-card {text-align:left;}.. plz try this code